# 'uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::ItemSearch' for Ruby on Rails app using amazon API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application where I am trying to have a text box allowing for searches on amazon using their API. So far I have the code below based on the AWS SDK I found in their documentation:

```
AWS.config(access_key_id: 'myaccesskey', secret_access_key:  'mysecretaccesskey', region: 'us-west- 2')


is = ItemSearch.new( 'Books', { 'Title' => 'ruby programming' } )
puts is
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

'uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::ItemSearch'

what do I need to do to make this work, I don't see a lot of good documentation for beginners and just want to learn how to set up my app to query data.